# When is multimap preferred over map?

Tags: stl, dictionary, multimap

Can anyone please tell me that when do we prefer multimap over map?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858127/multiset-multimap-whats-the-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) when you want to allow the same key values in your map.